# How can I enter numbers in the bar on the django form?

Tags: javascript, html, django, django-views

## What you want to achieve

[image: イメージ説明]

I want to input numbers in the django form like this.

## Current code

```
class Comment_movie_CreateForm (ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment_movie
        fields = ('comment','stars')
    comment = forms.CharField (required = False, label ='comment', max_length = 1000)
    stars = forms.FloatField (required = False, label ='stars', widget = forms.TextInput (
       attrs = {'type':'range','id':'form_homework', "class": "no_resize",'min': '0','max': '10','step': '0.1' })))
    def clean (self):
        cleaned_data = super (). clean ()
        return cleaned_data
    def clean_stars (self):
        stars = self.cleaned_data ['stars']
        if stars! = None:
            if stars <0 or stars> 10:
                raise forms.ValidationError ("The rating input is incorrect.")
            return stars
        else: else:
            raise forms.ValidationError ("The rating input is incorrect.")
    def clean_comment (self):
        comment = self.cleaned_data ['comment']
        if len (comment)> 1000:
            raise forms.ValidationError ("There are too many characters.")
        elif len (comment) == 0:
            raise forms.ValidationError ("Please enter the characters.")
        return comment
    def __init__ (self, * args, ** kwargs):
        super () .__ init__ (* args, ** kwargs)
        self.label_suffix = ""
```

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form }}
        {% if comment_tv %}
        <button type="submit">Edit Comment</button>
        <button type="submit" name="action" value="delete">Delete Comment</button>
        {% else %}
        <button type="submit">Post Comment</button>
        {% endif %}
    </form>
```

## What you want to ask

How would you change it to look like the photo?
Is this adjusted with CSS? Or is it javascript?

Comment: You need to do it with JavaScript, for django doesn't matter how data looks from users point of view, only matters what it recieve. Css is only `how it looks` you can't pass variables with css

Comment: The easiest way, not to use `modelform` but use regular form, and you could assign for your `starts input` and id, which later you can modify with javascript

Comment: I can't think of a way to do this, can I get a code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy way is:

```
attrs = {'type':'range', ...
```

but it is not works everywhere https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type_range.asp

Comment: In change, the slide bar appears, but the numbers do not appear.